# Does COPY utility in Cassandra have parameters that allows Special symbols and Comma separated strings in a single column to insert?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

We are having the below problems with data import using COPY utility.

1. COPY command isn't allowing special symbols like €, ¥ while data loading and this fails to insert the data in the table from CSV.
   Do we have any extra parameters for the COPY command that will allow the special symbols?

sample.csv

```
id                                   symbols
68f963d0-55a3-4453-9897-51c10c099499   $
41f172d6-0939-410a-bcde-5bcf96509710   €
50f925e7-c840-485c-bec0-23711c79ea11   ¥
c3ccc350-5734-42c4-a07d-9647f72c4236   $
```

"currency" is the table name with id as partion key.

```
COPY currency from 'sample.csv' with header=true;
```

-> This load only records with $ symbol but skips 2nd and 3rd records where symbols are €, ¥

2. How to skip comma(,)in a column and insert the complete string using COPY command?
   I have the following values for a column(COMMENTS) in csv and want to insert them in cassandra table. Here in this case COMMA is treated as next column value as csv is comma separated. Do we have any feature/parameters that
   allows COMMA(,) in the single columns using COPY COMMAND.
   Tried with

   COPY TABLENAME from 'test.csv' with header=true and QUOTE='"';

But couldn't load the below columns data which are COMMA separated in the single column.

```
Ex:
COMMENTScolumn
"Exact", "and $210/mt MLR China at most"
Since it’s a mill as indi,bid
"Range, and $430/mt FOB India at most"
```

Couldn't find any parameters for [COPY command utility](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html).

```
Versions
Cassandra 2.1.13
cqlsh 5.0.1
```

Comment: currency data type is "text" in the table schema @Abhishek

Comment: @arjun, have you got any solution?

Answer (score -1):

1) Support for special characters

I am using cqlsh 5.0.1 with Cassandra 3.0.2 and I am able to load € and other symbols from csv file into cassandra using cqlsh. Can you specify your cqlsh version also so I can check in that one.

2) Support of comma inside a String

I will suggest to use a different delimiter while using Copy To command and then use the same delimiter for Copy From Command.

Ex:
COPY global to 'global.csv' WITH DELIMITER='|';

COPY global from 'global.csv' WITH DELIMITER='|';

This way you can escape commas in your Strings.

Comment: 1. Can you tell me the datatype used for inserting currency?

Comment: I am using text for this

Comment: Abhishek, the special characters will be inserting using "insert" statements and when did the same using COPY command, didn't work. Did you load csv using COPY?